# Event receipt sent as PDF failing

Tags: civievent, pdf

Civicrm 4.7.18, 4.7.20 - selecting Admin/System Settings/Misc/Attach pdf copy to receipts results in error msg “The row #24 could not be found, please file an issue in the tracker with the HTML code”

In Sandbox Master (WP), register for event Fall Fundraiser w/PDF receipt selected. Thank You page ('master.demo.civicrm.org/?page=CiviCRM&q=civicrm/event/register&page_id=5') results in WSOD.  Select 'no' for PDF receipt, Thank You page finishes successfully.

Comment: Did this previously work?

Comment: Sandbox error is http 500,  wpmaster.demo.civicrm.org is currently unable to handle this request.

Comment: Same error in 4.6 - wp46.demo.civicrm.org is currently unable to handle this request.
HTTP ERROR 500

Comment: My gut says the sandbox isn't configured for handling the PDF generation.  But I leave that to someone with knowledge of that server.

Comment: Hi all, it isn't the sandbox but some line in the Registration Confirmation online message template, in CRM_Core_BAO_MessageTemplate::sendTemplate line 410 or so, (the html), I can test this in my local system but Sandbox won't let me modify message template.  Also CRM_Contribute_BAO_Contribution::sendmail fails (line 4722) same sort of thing